# Insert query not working with playframework reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am currently using,

- Scala 2.12.6,
- Mongo 2.4.9,
- PlayFramework 2.6

**URL** : http://localhost:9000/create?name=Ramesh&age=28
**METHOD** : GET
**Route** : GET    /create                    controllers.MyController.create(name: String, age: Int)

results in Execution Exception as below,
`[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(CommandError[code=<unknown>, errmsg=no such cmd: insert, doc: {"ok":0,"errmsg":"no such cmd: insert","bad cmd":{"insert":"persons","documents":[{"name":"Ramesh","age":28}],"ordered":true,"writeConcern":{"w":1,"wtimeout":null}}}]),WrappedArray())))))]`

**Created Mongo Collection as :** 
`def collection: Future[JSONCollection] = database.map(_.collection[JSONCollection]("persons"))`

**Action for Create :**

```
def create(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
    collection.flatMap(_.insert(Json.obj("name" -> name, "age" -> age))).map { _ =>
      Created
    }
  }
```

- I can find the records from MongoDB, there is no problem with that, but still not able to insert even a single word in the DB

Need help me over this.

Comment: MongoDB 2.4.9? [Really](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life)?

Comment: yes it is the version i used @cchantep

Comment: This version is no longer supported by MongoDB, neither by the driver